# How to identity whether It is MVC application or Web API application. I have many projects under one solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have many projects under one solution and all project look similar whether it is mvc or web api.
I am new to the project so how will I identify whether it is mvc or web api project.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: MVC controlers are derived from [`Controller` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller) that is member of [`System.Web.Mvc` namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc). Web API controllers are derived from [`ApiController` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.web.http.apicontroller) that is member of [`System.Web.Http` namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.web.http).

Answer (score 7):

Web Api project will be having the class WebApiConfig.cs inside of App_Start folder and MVC application will not be having any class like that in App_Start folder so this is the difference between mvc and web api application.
[Screenshot_Diff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0uet.png)

Answer (score 6):

See the base class of controller in web project if it is inheriting from ApiController it is web api else MVC if inheriting from Controller class.

**Example:**
For web api:

```
public class MyApiController : ApiController
```

For Mvc:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
```

Or you can create MVC and Web api projects using visual studio and see which one matches your solution.

Answer (score 1):

(in 2022 Visual Studio version) if you create either MVC or Web Api empty Project (**.NET Framework**) ,you will notice the base class(**HomeController**.cs) is created with inherited class **Controller**

But,you can distinguish both type of project by going **Global.asax** file  and look at Class name mentioned.It should be **WebApiApplication** for WebApiProject
and **MvcApplication** for MVC project.

```
 public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
```

```
 public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create solution folders each layer.For example, infrastructure,domain etc.And then you can give names to api projects like "ABC.Service.Api" and move these projects to releated solution folder.
Check the github projects for the folder or project structures.

Answer (score 0):

A warning for others trying to figure out whether a web app is MVC or Web API: Sometimes they're both.

In the web apps I'm looking at there will often be an `Index.cshtml` in the Views folder, and a `HomeController` that inherits from `Controller`, suggesting an MVC app.  However, there will be other controllers that inherit from `ApiController`.

In my case the `HomeController` will generally be very basic, with maybe just an `Index` action, and the other controllers inheriting from `ApiController` will have many more actions.  So it appears the apps are generally Web API apps with one or two very basic web pages as well.